# Nested location with alias

Tags: configuration, nginx, location, alias

I have a directory/web app that is located outside of the web root directory of my site.

Say the site is here:

```
/var/www/site/htdocs/
```

And the external app is located here:

```
/var/www/apps/coolapp/
```

My question is how can I configure nginx to map/route all requests that are like `www.mysite.com/coolapp/*` (asterisk being wildcard) to the external location `/var/www/apps/coolapp/`? For example, www.mysite.com/coolapp/test.php should server `/var/www/apps/coolapp/test.php`.

I have added an `alias` directive in `production.conf` that the main `nginx.conf` file includes. This worked fine for everything except .php files because there is another `location` that is catching .php files instead. So I nested a `location` in with the `alias` to catch .php files, but now nginx is telling me it can't find the .php files "404 File Not Found". Here is what `production.conf` currently looks like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /blah/blah/blah;
    ssl_certificate_key /blah/blah/blah;
    ssl_protocols       blah blah blah;
    ssl_ciphers         blahblahblah;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers blahblah;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.mysite.com-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.mysite.com-error.log error;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/site/htdocs;

    include conf/magento_rewrites.conf;
    include conf/magento_security.conf;
    include /var/www/site/nginx/*.conf;

    #-------CODE IN QUESTION-------
    location  /coolapp/ {
        alias  /var/www/apps/coolapp/;
        location ~ \.php {
            # Copied from "# PHP Handler" below
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            rewrite_log on;

            # By default, only handle fcgi without caching
            include conf/magento_fcgi.conf;
        }
    }

    # PHP handler
    location ~ \.php {
      ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
      if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

      ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
      fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
      fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
      fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
      rewrite_log on;

      # By default, only handle fcgi without caching
      include conf/magento_fcgi.conf;
    }

    # 404s are handled by front controller
    location @magefc {
        rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$query_string last;
    }

    # Last path match hands to magento or sets global cache-control
    location / {
        ## Maintenance page overrides front controller
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @magefc;
        expires 24h;
    }
}
```

conf/magento_fcgi.conf looks like this:

```
fastcgi_pass phpfpm;

## Tell the upstream who is making the request
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_redirect off;

# Ensure the admin panels have enough time to complete large requests ie: report generation, product import/export
proxy_read_timeout 1600s;

# Ensure PHP knows when we use HTTPS
fastcgi_param  HTTPS           $fastcgi_https;

## Fcgi Settings
include                        fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_connect_timeout        120;
fastcgi_send_timeout           320s;
fastcgi_read_timeout           1600s;
fastcgi_buffer_size            128k;
fastcgi_buffers 512            64k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size      128k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size   256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors       off;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/apps/coolapp$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
# nginx will buffer objects to disk that are too large for the buffers above
fastcgi_temp_path              /tmpfs/nginx/tmp 1 2;
#fastcgi_keep_conn              on; # NGINX 1.1.14
expires                        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
```

Here are some errors messages I pulled from error.log

```
2014/02/28 11:10:17 [error] 9215#0: *933 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,   .................   client: x.x.x.x, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /coolapp/test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://[::1]:9000", host: "www.mysite.com"  
2014/02/28 11:10:17 [error] 9215#0: *933 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,  client: x.x.x.x, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /coolapp/test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.mysite.com"  
2014/02/28 11:11:59 [error] 9220#0: *1193 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /coolapp/test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.mysite.com"
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We can't see what's wrong because it's likely in the `mage_rewrites.conf`.

Comment: After some testing, it appears that `$uri` isn't updated when an alias directive is used: `$uri` will still be prefixed with `/coolapp/`.  This may be a bug, as it contradicts the documentation.  I'm pretty sure that's how `root` is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, second read after coffee. Get the SCRIPT_FILENAME out of the included fastcgi configuration and set it in both location blocks. If this doesn't fix things then in the coolapp location hardcode the doc root path and see if that fixes things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you show what the code would look like for `in the coolapp location hardcode the doc root path`? From what it sounds like, you want me to put `root /var/www/site/htdocs;` there, which I don't see how that will help, as that should be inherited I thought.

Comment: In the bit fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME, replace $document_root with `/var/www/apps/coolapp`. I suspect the variable to be cluttered and hardcoding it will rule out of our confirm.

Comment: Ah, very nice. I think I'm getting closer.. I have changed that line to `/var/www/apps/coolapp$fastcgi_script_name;` That shouldn't be needed in both location blocks, just one matching php files, right? If so, it should be fine in the fcgi.conf. But I am still getting the same results. I will update my code in post and also add nginx error messages.

Comment: Is it necessary to restart php-fpm when making these changes? Not that it helped, just wondering if I need to keep doing that as I'd rather not have to if not necessary :)

Comment: Ah I got it! Needed to replace `$document_root` with `/var/www/apps`! Thanks, you led me to answer :)

Comment: To be honest it is not a good solution yet, cause it means $document_root has the wrong value.

Comment: I don't think so. The $document_root is correct, but the coolapp location is in a different location. Unless the `alias` is supposed to change the $document_root or something..?

Comment: Quote from [nginx.org](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables): "`$document_root`: root or alias directive’s value for the current request".  Your `$document_root` is borked; you should figure out what it is and correct it.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed in a newer version.  As long as `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is set to `$request_filename`, it should work as expected.  (This differs from previous versions, where `$request_filename` wouldn't work in all cases.)  Additionally, you need to omit any `try_files` directive in the inner location block.  Re-evaluating `$uri` appears to throw off `$request_filename`.